# WhatsApp old account recovery

Tags: whatsapp

My old phone was stolen. So, I didn't logged in my WhatsApp account for about 3 months. After buying a new phone I created a new account with new number (as I didn't have the old one then) and was added by my friends in an old group. But my old number was still added in that group. So with the MI dual apps facility I logged in with my old number in some days. Now there are no groups or profile pic or chat history or anything. However, there was immediately a message in that group that my old number has left the group. Now can I get my groups back?